# Django- How to revert the changes accidentally made?

Tags: python, django

So I was trying to get Django to work on my PC, I has having some troubles so I looked for answers here on StackOverflow.

I found this:

[No module named django.core when creating project in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281771/no-module-named-django-core-when-creating-project-in-virtualenv)

The situation is exactly the same, so I used the first answer and it worked.

Basically in the answer he says to use this command:

```
ftype Python.File="E:\Python27\YOUR_ENVIRONMENT\Scripts\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

And it worked, I didn't get any more Django related errors and I could create the Django project.

But I knew that I changed something, I just didn't know what, so I tried to run a Python project outside my virtual environment, and now it doesn't run them.

Can someone explain what did I change and how can I undo it?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you modified the enviorment variable for your python interpeter.

With the command you just wrote you are using the python created inside your virtualenv

You need to set it back to the python.exe executable installed in your system.

Check this link:
https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts

Read it carefully and set your variable back to where you have your python.exe, something like this:

> ftype Python.File=C:\Path\to\pythonw.exe "%1" %*

Also read the last line of the stackoverflow question you linked:

> Just be sure to set it back to the original value when you're done.